# Biblatex fails to read bbl-file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texstudio, bbl

Why is Biblatex not working? I know it did, when I used it on my old system.
As you see in the screenshot it seems to recognize my bib-file, but fails at interpreting its own bbl file. I don't have a clue what's going on here.

The blg file contains some error messages.

```
[0] Config.pm:327> INFO - This is Biber 2.3
[0] Config.pm:330> INFO - Logfile is 'protokoll.blg'
[30] biber-MSWIN:284> INFO - === 
[52] Biber.pm:346> INFO - Reading 'protokoll.bcf'
[125] Utils.pm:147> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9
[126] Biber.pm:689> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[130] Biber.pm:3066> INFO - Processing section 0
[155] Biber.pm:3206> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'literatur.bib' for section 0
[194] bibtex.pm:1062> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[196] bibtex.pm:923> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'literatur.bib'
[226] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[227] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[228] Biber.pm:2943> INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'de_DE'
[228] Biber.pm:2947> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de_DE'
[241] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[242] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[242] Biber.pm:2943> INFO - Sorting list 'nty' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'de_DE'
[242] Biber.pm:2947> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de_DE'
[244] bbl.pm:505> INFO - Writing 'protokoll.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[245] bbl.pm:596> INFO - Output to protokoll.bbl
[245] Biber.pm:107> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

I will ad a minimal example if necessary, although I think the TeX file is not the problem here.

[image: Screenshot]

Miktex 2.9, TexStudio (pdfLatex, Biber)

My complete log in TexStudio:
(What does the last entry mean? I tried pressing F8 (Bibliographie) before F5. It didn't work.)

```
Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition. \sortlist{
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \sortlist{nty}
Undefined control sequence. \entry{demtr1}{book}{}
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \entry{kuchling}{book}{}
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endentry
Undefined control sequence. \endsortlist
Extra \endgroup. \begin{document}

Citation 'demtr1' on page 3 undefined
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (61.5431pt too wide) in paragraph
Float too large for page by 18.04808pt
Citation 'kuchling' on page 11 undefined
Empty bibliography
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) protokoll(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Comment: Please add the used code here.  Then we can copy it, compile it on our own computer and check where the error is. Just help us to help you!  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This errors normally mean version problems. Probably you have an bbl created by an older biber but your biblatex is newer. Check the blg-file.

Comment: Thanks! I added the conent of the blg to my OP. Apparently Biber expected Biblatex 2.9 instead of 3.0

Comment: I thought an Update with the MikTex Package Manager would fix this issue, but it didn't. I'm going to try fixing it by switching back to Biblatex 2.9 (Not sure how it's done yet)

Comment: Please note that the `biblatex control file version` does not coincide with the `biblatex` version. So downgrading to `biblatex` 2.9 won't help you here, the correct match would be `biblatex` 3.2 with Biber 2.3. But an update should help, if you are using MikTeX make sure to do the update in both Admin and User mode (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864)). (Make sure you didn't install Biber manually.) After the update you should have Biber 2.4 and `biblatex` 3.3. Then clean the auxiliary files (`.bbl`, `.aux`, `.bcf`) and compile from a clean directory. Things should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe this nails down the solution to my problem. Unfortunately the databases of Miktex (Version 5. Apr 16) only seem to provide Biber 2.3. I synchronized in Miktex package manager (as admin and not as admin) but the blg still states it was using Biber 2.3. I copied the tex and bib files into a fresh folder.

Comment: Nope, MikTeX definitely has Biber 2.4. Have you updated in both User and Admin mode? Are you sure you haven't installed Biber manually? If you start the Package Manager (User and Admin) is Biber shown as installed?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. It is *not* enough to synchronise the package manager, you will also have to run the Updater programme in both modes (it could be that you have to run each of those twice because of system updates). If you synchronise the package manager you tell MikTeX to get a list with the newest versions of the packages. You will still have to run the actual updater to do the updated (i.e. install new packages).

Comment: I made a mistake right in the beginning. I started the manager "as admin", not the admin version. However using the Update wizard results in an internal error (MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 10586
SystemAdmin: yes). (Is that the reason it didn't work out automatically?) So I deinstalled miktex-biber-bin and installed it again. This finally worked; problem solved. Thank you again!

Comment: Don't know what the internal error was about. It could be that the installation was corrupted or a process was blocking the updater, or ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a software update. The versions of Biber and `biblatex` didn't match. See comments above.